# Indirect Sum A1C1 notation for multiple cells Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a formula to sum things in a range of rows.

So my "input" cell says: `R1@,R5@,R6@,R9@`

And my current formula to "parse" it says: `=SUM(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(inputcell,"@","C"&COLUMN()),FALSE))`

The result parses to: `=SUM(INDIRECT("R1C9,R5C9,R6C9,R9C9"),FALSE)` which is exactly what I had hoped. Only it doesn't work.

This I had hoped would be equal to `Sum(I1,I5,I6,I9)` but sadly fails with #REF. Even sum(indirect("I1,i5,i6,i9")) fails too.

It seems indirect understands `i8:i10` but does not understand `i8,i9,i10` which is what I need.  Could anyone find me a way to get around it?

Comment: Wouldn't indirect understand `I8,I9,I10` if it was enclosed in brackets `()` rather than quotes?

Comment: You could try building your whole formula as a string and then using EVALUATE() to process it. EVALUATE() function doesn't work in a formula but you can use this trick I found the other day https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/evaluate-function.html

Comment: Where is your formula going, what cell? Where is the Input cell?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with (I run it in about 30 columns):

`=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(148,COLUMN()),TRUE),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(158,COLUMN()),TRUE),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(166,COLUMN()),TRUE),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(179,COLUMN()),TRUE))`

This is not ideal. As I want to have the formula able to sum an arbitrary amount of numbers, not just a specific 4. But for now it will have to do.

`SumIf/SumIfs` would work best (by far!), but I didn't want to touch columns.